# only route certain addresses through PPTP VPN?

Tags: linux, vpn, routing

after the pptp is up, I found there is an entry in route table:

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev ppp5
default via 192.168.1.1 dev vlan2  metric 1
```

This directs all outgoing traffics through 10.0.0.1 which is the VPN gateway. But I want route all traffic through local gateway 192.168.1.1 except certain address for example 172.217.26.36.
I try to delete the `default via 10.0.0.1 dev ppp5`. Then try to add a new entry:

```
ip route add 172.217.26.36 via 10.0.0.1 dev ppp5
```

this always failed with: `RTNETLINK answers: No such process`

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subnet mask is required, the proper command would be:

`ip route add 10.0.0.1/32 dev ppp5`

`ip route add 172.217.26.36/32 via 10.0.0.1 dev ppp5`

[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-route-add/)

Comment: # ip route add 172.217.26.36/32 via 10.0.0.1 dev ppp5
RTNETLINK answers: No such process

Comment: @Wang it doesn't know what 10.0.0.1 is because you deleted the default route, you need to add a gateway first. I updated my answer.